# Cam-operated clamps: When are logarithmic cams preferred and when are involute cams preferred?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, mechanisms, machine-design, machine-elements

Logarithmic cams are used in rock climbing, but involute cams are used to clamp work pieces when machining.  Why are cams with two different profiles preferred for these two applications, which seem to have the same goal?

Comment: Is the logarithmic cam easier to release due to the cam profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- if an involute of a circle is turned uniformly around its center, then the tangents to the involute move in a uniform translation motion.
- the mechanical advantage is greater when the gap is just below the maximum range with small deviation
- the offset is optimal for repeated gap sizes for a consistent angle of handle and thus not suitable for a random wide range of gaps unlike the logarithmic cams

[next](http://www.mozimtec.de/a1.html)
[image]
[image] [from](https://www.pinterest.ca/pin/778278379355520082/)

[next](http://www.vainokodas.com/climbing/cams.html)

[image]

The dual logarithmic cam has two advantages for climbers

- the engagement serves over a wide ratio of gaps.
- the mean contact point below horizontal pin axis is constant for any gap and depends on the log factor and thus a constant gear ratio
  r = eµø
  a = tan-1(µ)

Answer (score 1):

If the scroll on a lathe chuck is what you had in mind for involute spiral used to fix and locate workpieces for machining then it is very obvious when you have the lathe chuck in front of you and swap the jaws on the chuck.

Each jaw in the lathe chuck has teeth cut into its back which ride along spiral grooves of the scroll, not unlike how a nut rides along the the threads of a bolt, but instead of the threads going around each other in a axially along the length of cylinder, they move radially in a circular plane.

Go to the link to view the GIF animation (it is too large for me to post directly on here such that it animates).
[image]
https://dribbble.com/shots/1129158-Scroll-Chuck

The logarithmic spiral has variable spacing between the spiral grooves so the fixed teeth on the jaws and would suffer from either slop or jam, whereas an involute cam can be made to have constant spacing.

[image]
http://www.constructorscorner.net/ideas_and_gadgets/math/math_hunch/hunch_00001/temp_hunches/involute_vs_logarithmic_spiral.htm